# How to add an space between Tabs using TabView?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using TabView for my Tabs, and my issue is that I'm not sure how to move **Tabs 4 and 5** all the way to the **right side** maybe doing something like:

```
float: right
```

Basically I would like to add an space between Tab 3 and Tab 4 so that Tab 4 and 5 can move all the way to the right side. Finally, I would like to add a background color maybe yellow so that all Tabs from 1 to 5 can have the same background.

Here's my code:
[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/P6YhZBqhJiG4vF5xudvk?p=preview)

Comment: Do you want a margin between tab3 and 4 or you want tab 4 and tab 5 to move all the way to right of the container?

Comment: I want tab 4 and 5 to move all the way to the right, and then add a background (yellow) so it's the same background for all the tabs from 1 to 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this..

```
/* set diplay of the container */
.ui-tabview .ui-tabview-nav{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

/* this will make a margin to the left of tab 4
that will make tab 4 and tab 5 to float/positioned to right */
.ui-tabview.ui-tabview-top > .ui-tabview-nav li:nth-child(4){
  margin-left:auto;
}

/* change all the background of the tab button */
.ui-state-default{
  background:yellow!important;
}
/* change the background of the tab container */
.ui-tabview .ui-tabview-nav{
  background:yellow!important;
}
```

Please see this live code https://plnkr.co/edit/mcgS1yIWG1Y0flgA9hbc?p=preview

Hope this helps.